# how to combine database fields into 1

Tags: mysql

I'm want to combine address fields into 1.

address)100 noway ln

city) eastjablip

state) No

combined into:
address) 100 noway ln, eastjablip, no

While leaving city and state intact. (needed for search option)

Thanks

Comment: u want to combine on select query or u want to change field type?...

Answer (score 3):

Use `concat_ws` ("concatenate with separator")

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(', ', address, city, state) ....
```

Comment: Will I need to run this every so often to update new user info?

Comment: You can also create insert and update triggers so that it will automatically do this every time users add or update a row.

Comment: I'm checking the address field in the Db and nothing is changing.

Comment: I'm running a script that pulls from the address table on my Db, unfortunately it doesn't pull the city and state tables. I was wanting to combine the address, city and state under the *address* table so the script can get the right info.

Comment: Oh so city address and state are not even in the same table? How do you know which address goes with which city, what's the table structure like?